# Retrofit Android basic and simple issue

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My server returns simple Json result like below,

```
{"message":"Upload Success.!"}
```

I am trying to get the result into Retrofit Model class

```
public class MyResponse {
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;
}
```

My interface class is here

```
public interface MyService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/")
    public retrofit2.Call<MyResponse> saveFile(@Part("filename") String fileName, @Part("photo") RequestBody photo);
}
```

this is how i try to fetch the result

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setLenient()
                            .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://xxxxxxx.com/fileupload.php/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();

MyService service = retrofit.create(MyService.class);

retrofit2.Call<MyResponse> call = service.saveFile(filename, requestbody);

retrofit2.Response<MyResponse> response = call.execute();
```

But i cannot bind the result to the `MyResponse` class

The result it

```
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
02-23 21:22:43.074 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:72)
02-23 21:22:43.075 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-23 21:22:43.075 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
02-23 21:22:43.075 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
02-23 21:22:43.075 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
02-23 21:22:43.075 20293-20410/retrofitquictest.com.retrofitquicktest W/System.err:     ... 8 more
```

I guess I'm doing small mistake here. can someone identify that please ?

Comment: Can you show your retrofit interface? And you also need to log correct server message. Because it may contain some characters which make it become String only.

Comment: can you show the server response?, may be the response is not a jsonObject but a String

Comment: Your json is properly encode from php side

Comment: updated the question with interface guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to retrofit documentation your base url should only consist the first part of url in your case:
Base url should be `"http://xxxxxxx.com/`
and add the other part in Post like this `@POST("fileupload.php/")`. Give it a try maybe it will work for you.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

please check response in PostMan, if in postman you get same response as you told then this means that in your app you are getting error response which is in string format, thats why you are getting this type mismatch exception.

Comment: yes, this means in your app you are getting something like this in response ("unable to submit data"), thats why you got exception.

Comment: for now simply replace your model class with String type, to check what response you are getting in your app

Comment: Data goes to server.  The issue in only when i get response.

Comment: yes, but change model type to String type to just check

Comment: I checked by changing to string. But i get no error and i get 200 code. But i want to bind the result to model class. Because this is a testing project.

Comment: try call.enque(), instead of call.execute()