# Android Retrofit POST request doesn't work but in Postman it works

Tags: android, node.js, post, retrofit2

I find same problem this
[Android Retrofit - POST request doesn't work, but in Postman it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550437/android-retrofit-post-request-doesnt-work-but-in-postman-it-works#)

But I could not solve it

this is gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

this is my code to post request in android

```
static final String URL = "http://localhost:3000/";

     public void map(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("gender", UserSex);
    map.put("age", UserAge);
    map.put("name", UserName);
    map.put("password", UserPw);
    map.put("email", UserEmail);

    GitHubService gitHubService = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
    Call<RetrofitRepo> call = gitHubService.getUserItem(map);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RetrofitRepo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RetrofitRepo> call, Response<RetrofitRepo> response) {
            try {
                RetrofitRepo repoList = response.body();
                String message = repoList.getmessage();
                String token = repoList.gettoken();

                if (message.equals("registered successfully")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserEnroll.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "register success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "register failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RetrofitRepo> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

and this is interface

```
public interface GitHubService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/auth/login")
Call<RetrofitRepo> getPost(
        @Field("username") String username
);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/auth/placeSearch")
Call<RetrofitRepo> getPlaceID(
        @Field("placeID") String placeID
);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/auth/login")
Call<RetrofitRepo> getItem(
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> option
);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/auth/register")
Call<RetrofitRepo> getUserItem(
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> option
);
```

}

i use node js this is response code

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {
const { email, password, name, age, gender } = req.body
let newUser = null

const create = (user) => {
    if(user) {
        throw new Error('email exists')
    } else {
        return User.create(email, password, name, age, gender)
    }
}

const count = (user) => {
    newUser = user
    return User.count({}).exec()
}

const assign = (count) => {
    if(count === 1) {
        return newUser.assignAdmin()
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(false)
    }
}

const respond = (isAdmin) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'registered successfully',
        admin: isAdmin ? true : false
    })
}

const onError = (error) => {
    res.status(409).json({
        message: error.message
    })
}

User.findOneByEmail(email)
.then(create)
.then(count)
.then(assign)
.then(respond)
.catch(onError)}
```

I requested using a postman and it worked

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register
{
"email": "test6@google.com",
"password": "abc123@",
"name": "user",
"age": "18",
"gender": "F"}
```

POST /api/auth/register 409 13.393 ms - 26 or 
POST /api/auth/register 200 15.064 ms - 51 it responded in node

but its not work on my android app using retrofit
and not responded in node

Comment: Can you share the what's coming in the log?

Comment: try using @Body in                                                                                       
@POST("api/auth/register")
Call<RetrofitRepo> getUserItem(@Body RequestBody option);

Comment: What you are getting in response? any response code like 400....

Comment: Can you show how you are making API call in post man(span)?

Comment: for me it was filesize issue please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55913121/3904109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check Whether you had put your **Server OnLine**
2. Verify the **URL** that you had Requested is **Correct**.
3. If you are using Emulator use IP as 10.0.2.2 and if a real device is using use same network and use IP of the System

**static final String URL = "http://IPADRESSOFSERVER:3000/";**

For Emulator use **static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";**

Use **same network for connecting to local network**. and Use the **Ip Adderess of the System**. **Turn off** the **System Firewall and Antivirus** too.

Open your browser (Chrome Recommended) and type "http://IPADRESSOFSERVER:3000/someWebpageHOstedOnline". IF it is accessable check the retrofit call. else the Device cant create connection to the server

Add

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
    res.send(Hello This is a Test);
});
```

in your js file and try accessing http://IPADRESSOFSERVER:3000/test

Comment: i checked that 1. yes server is online 2. URL is correct 3. i'm not using emulator and i try my ip but its not work.. thank you for your suggestions. if you know other solution please tell me

Comment: @Jshin Open your browser (Chrome Recommended) and type "http://IPADRESSOFSERVER:3000/someWebpageHOstedOnline". IF it is accessable check the retrofit call. else the Device cant create connection to the server.  This is to check whether device is connecting to the Server properly .

Comment: use ipadress of the system always instead of localhost. And make sure that the port is open for extenal connection by turning of firwall ad by adding inbound law

Comment: @Jshin may be your firewall blocks an outside request. Check it by the above method.

Comment: i try that pc and mobile, pc "http://ipaddress:3000/api/auth/register" is correct response but mobile is responded timed out error and i use wifi router in my pc. Is this related to the problem?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: Did you try it by turning of both firewall and ativirus. The timeout occurs due to your mobile device cant access the server

Comment: i using windows 10 on my pc

Comment: Turn of windows firewall, defender and antivirus. Add a url in your js file and test whether it can be accessed using the chrome

Comment: really thank you! i turn off the window firewall, antivirus and i restart server its work! Thank you so much bro!

Comment: Happy to hear that Bro. Thank You. Happy Coding Bro

Answer (score 0):

Your need to user your computer or laptop's IP Address in your base URL

```
static final String URL = "http://yourIPAddress:3000/";
```

example :

> static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.100:3000/";

Comment: i use that too but it same result

Comment: have you added INTERNET permission in your menifest file ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> yes i already added it too but its not work..