# Api work with Postman but not in android application

Tags: java, android

A method build in Java using Jersey which takes two parameters and store in database it works properly with the postman but when I use it in Android Application it not work. I try to send a request using Volley and Retrofit.

Server Side Code:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/register")
public Boolean registerUser(@FormParam("userName") String userName, @FormParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.println(userName+"\t"+password);
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO user(user_name,password,status) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    try {
        Connection con = MyConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prst = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        prst.setString(1, userName);
        prst.setString(2, password);
        prst.setInt(3, 0);
        int count = prst.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
        System.out.println(count+" Row inserted");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Android Code :

public void register(final String userName, final String password) {

```
    User user = new User(userName, password, 1);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.13:8080/Demo_Application/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    JsonPlaceholderApi jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderApi.class);

    Call<List<User>> call = jsonPlaceholderApi.register("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("Response","Something went wrong."+response.toString());
                return;
            }

            Log.d("Response",response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZPDg.png)

Volley Request:

public void registerVolley(final String userName, final String password){

```
    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("userName", userName);
    param.put("password",password);

    JsonObjectRequest arrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.0.26:8080/Demo_Application/rs/test/register", new JSONObject(param), new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("Response", response.toString());
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Response", error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("userName", userName);
            param.put("password",password);

            return param;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> header =  new HashMap<>();
            header.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return header;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);

}
```

Comment: Where does Android get its database connection?  The android call can't possibly be direct to registerUser, can it?  We're going to need to see, like, the curl that your postman request is, and the curl that android is using.  I bet if you put those 2 together, you are going to find the problem on your own.

Also, passwords into some database in clear text?  Are you guys nuts?

Comment: at the server end, I am unable to get userName and password.Is @FormParams works with android request.

Comment: Please have mercy on Rest API. and find tutorials using retrofit or volley.  Your are mixing Retrofit , Volley and Httpclinet  together.

Comment: what do you think is it work, when I request using Volley. @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: There is nothing to think. user particular one way. either use retrofit or volley. don't mess up all together

Comment: I use both one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for retrofit:

```
JsonPlaceholderApi  jsonPlaceholderApi  = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderApi.class);
    Call<Boolean> call = jsonPlaceholderApi.sign("userName", "password");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("Response","Something went wrong."+response.toString());
                return;
            }

            Log.d("Response",response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Your method inside jsonPlaceholderApi  :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("rs/test/register")
    Call<ResponseLogin> signIn(
            @Field("userName") String userName,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
```

Comment: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 6 path $

Comment: null null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_name' cannot be null
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Is your above code is of android or Server?If its of android, Please share your request which you have given in postman, I will give you the retrofit code.

Comment: Ok.Because your response is returning boolean and you are expecting list in android.Please share your retrofit code and response you are getting in postman.

Comment: See your server code is returning boolean and you are expecting <List<User>> call.How it will work?

Comment: I am not asking about return type, I ask about data sent by an Android device not received by the server.

Comment: Check my edited answer and let me know if its working or not

Comment: when I use volley what changes apply.

Answer (score 0):

Add Below Code in **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-keep class com.app.appname.model.** { *; }
```

NOTE: Change last line with your model folder